# Whats does -f mean in Interpretor Definition : !#/bin/awk -f

Tags: shell, unix, awk, interpreter, shebang

Whats does `-f` mean in Interpreter Definition :  `#!/bin/awk -f`
Its an `awk` script

Answer (score 1):

The `-f` command line option for `awk` specifies that the next argument should be the file to read the commands from.

If you omit the `-f`, the interpreter will try to invoke your script using `/bin/awk yourScriptFile` which will fail, e.g.:

```
$ cat yourScriptFile 
#!/bin/awk
{ print $1; }
$ ./yourScriptFile 
awk: cmd. line:1: ./yourScriptFile
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: ./yourScriptFile
awk: cmd. line:1:   ^ unterminated regexp
```

See the POSIX documentation for awk (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) or `man 1 awk` for details.

Comment: @abnv Please accept my answer if it best helps you.

Answer (score 1):

From [AWK man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7m50/index.html).

> ```
> -f progfile
> ```
>
> awk uses the set of patterns it reads from *progfile*.

This means that the script must be found in *progfile*.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from `man awk`:

> -f file        Program text is read from file instead of from the command line.  Multiple -f options are allowed.

Here is an example:

Giving awk a program using `-f filename`

```
$ cat script.awk 
{print}
$ awk -f script.awk <<< "abcd"
abcd
```

Or creating an awk executable like this:

```
$ cat script1.awk 
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{print}
$ ./script1.awk <<< "abcd"
abcd
```